# The connection between the rank of a matrix and its zero-mode eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would be most thankful if you could help me prove that if an arbitrary n by n matrix has rank m < n, then the matrix has (n-m) linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue zero. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the rank-nullity theorem.  What is the relationship between the nullspace of a matrix and its eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue zero?

Answer (score 1):

if rank of $A_{n*n}$ is $m <n$ then Ax=0 will have non trivel answer as $x_1 $and so 0 will be a $eigen value$ $Ax_1=0x_1$.

Now we try to find eigen vectors of zero egien value:
 (A-0I)x=0 Ax=0 and so $X_1$ and other non trivel answersof Ax=0 will be eigen vector correspondence with zero eigen value too
since Ax=0 has n-m independence answer so number of independ eigen vectors corresponding to 0 eigen value  is  n-m too!:)